# An issue of running Phonopy for graphene using Siesta

Tags: density-functional-theory, phonons, siesta, phonopy, supercell

I have used `Siesta` in the example attached with `phonopy` to run phonon for graphene, and when I typed the command to create force sets:

```
phonopy --siesta -f disp-001/Gr.FA
```

But I have got this error:

```
Number of files to be read (1) don't match to

the number of displacements (2) in phonopy_disp.yaml.

FORCE_SETS could not be created.
```

Thanks in advance to all

Comment: Do you also have a disp-002 file?

Comment: No I don't have it. I have only disp-001.

Comment: Could you attach (or link to) your files so we can take a look?